# React PureComponent

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to know the real use case on when to use **PureComponent** over Component in React? What is truly the difference between the two besides the fact that **PureComponent** implements **shouldComponentUpdate** method with shallow state checking. What is the true purpose of this API

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've kind of answered the question yourself. `React.Component` will **always update** if you haven't implemented a `shouldComponentUpdate` (even if the state is shallowly equal).

`React.PureComponent` will **not** not update following a shallow state check (assuming the state and props remained the same). So if you want to prevent unnecessary updates and don't want to have to implement your own `shouldComponentUpdate` function, then use `PureComponent` to help save boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I guess it still makes less sense to use it over basic Component